# Can't access site after plugin activation

Tags: facebook, fatal-error, calendar

I get the following error after adding multiple plugins, including All In One Event Calender and BackupWP. Now I can't access anything from within the admin panel or from the front-end. I can't get into the Plugins page to de-activate any problem plugin. Can anybody help me get back to a point where my site is usable?

```
Fatal error: 
    Cannot redeclare fb_admin_dialog() 
    (previously declared in /home/jomoxo/public_html/angelinesoatmealoriginals.com/wp-content/plugins/facebook/fb-wp-helpers.php:2) 
    in /home/jomoxo/public_html/angelinesoatmealoriginals.com/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar/lib/facebook-php-sdk/fb-wp-helpers.php 
    on line 11
```

Comment: Hi John, welcome to WPSE. Make sure you check out the [About](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/about) and [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) pages, since this site has some unique mechanics that you'll need to know about.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the error because the Facebook and All In One Event Calendar plugins are both declaring the `fb_admin_dialog()` function, but PHP only allows a function to be declared once.

To fix the immediate problem, log in to your server with S/FTP and rename the `wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar`  directory to something like `all-in-one-event-calendar-temp`; that will deactivate it and remove the error. You can also [disable all plugins with phpMyAdmin](http://www.stephanmiller.com/deactivate-wordpress-plugins-through-phpmyadmin/) or another database management tool, if you prefer that over the S/FTP method.

If you want to use both plugins, I'd recommend creating posts on their wordpress.org support forums, and asking the developers to check if the function has already been declared before trying to declare it. e.g.,

```
if( !function_exists( 'fb_admin_dialog' ) )
{
    function fb_admin_dialog()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```